# How to diagnose cause of sound stutters on mac pro

Tags: audio, usb, hardware, hdmi, mac-pro

I have ancient Mac Pro, a 2009 heavily upgrade: 2012 mother board, 12 core Xeon at 3.33 Ghz 96 GB ram.

It has an add on card with 5 USB ports, as several of the original ports no longer work.
(A way to trouble shoot USB ports?)

It has an upgraded video card AMD Radeon RX 580 with HDMI and displayport output.  One HDMI out is connected to a 43" hisense TV 4k for my display.

Through the Old Mac Legacy Project, I've been able to install Ventura on it, which is required to run some of the software I use.

This machine is the start of a music production system.

Externally the mac takes input from a Keylab 88 mk2 midi keyboard over USB  Output goes to Audient ID 14 Mixer, also over USB.  The Audient can also take optical.  Haven't tried this yet.

In playing, I get the occasional stutter.  The effect is similar to a cd skipping. A block of sound about 4 tenths of a second long will be repeated 2 extra times.

I have had this happen even on youtube, playing on the mac's internal speakers.

I'm nowhere near saturating this machine.  My CPU usage runs about 6%. Memory use is under 20 GB.

I'm at a bit of a loss to know how to attack this problem.

---

Ideas:

- That this happens even on internal speakers, suggests a bug in Apple's core audio.
- Try using an optical out to connect to the Audient.  Perhaps too many USB interupts. (but if that's the case why would I have observed it on internal speakers?)
- Extract audio using an hdmi or display port audio extractor connected to an extra vid port

But this is trial and error.  How do I find out the fundamental issue?

Edit in response to comemnts:

The ventura patch is a requirement.  See the Open Core Legacy Project.

https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/

This is a set of environment hacks that allow newer software to think it's running on older software with some additional kernel extensions to chink up some cracks.  I do not understand the wizard's spells.

Simplified test:

Audient not connected. Keylab not connect.

Run simple metronome program that chirps 75 times a minute.

Still happens.

Additional observation:

Unplug a usb mouse, and move it to another USB port.  On plugging in the mouse LED flashes once, but the mouse is not mousing.

If I reboot the machine at that point, without touching the mouse cable, and the mouse works fine.

This also has happened with keyboards.

Something about USB is upwhacked.

Comment: The very first thing you want to do is get to basics.  Boot the Mac without the complex setup including the patch to make ventura work (use a different drive if necessary)   Then, try to play some audio.  Do you still experience the stutter?

Comment: "Several of the original ports no longer work." What happened? It could be an issue with data bandwidth, particularly if the machine is now overstretched with a higher-spec GPU, a PCI card for USB; and you're running an OS which 'expects' a better/newer spec. Do you get the problem booting to an earlier OS? If you're doing pro-level music production, with brand new software that has last year's OS as its minimum, then really a 12-15 year-old Mac won't cut it. An M2 Pro Mac Mini with 32Gb RAM will be lightyears ahead. "Some outlay", I realise.

Comment: Response to your edit:  you have a bodged together setup to make things “work” on hardware it’s not supposed to.   You need to eliminate factors which is why I said to boot from an older OS from a different drive. If you’re not willing to start there, then you’re in for a rough go at this